# Adding domain alias for already running account @ domains.live.com

Tags: email, hotmail, windows-live

I'm really having some problems to get straight answer from Microsoft Community:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/admin-signin/adding-domain-alias-for-already-running-account/56b4cd27-b0ac-43be-af95-1df261f4aca2

so I will be posting my question here as maybe here someone will know the answer.

So my question:

Is it possible to add another domain (domain alias) for already running account @ domains.live.com ?

For example:

I got already running email accounts (on domains.live.com) with domain "mydomain.com" but I want to add "domain alias" that is "mydomain.net", "mydomain.org".

So I will have setup like this:

```
john.doe@mydomain.com
john.doe@mydomain.net
john.doe@mydomain.org
```

Is it possible to do so on domains.live.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into the same problem.

[This](http://www.gibixonline.com/post/2012/08/30/Creating-email-aliases-for-Domains-for-Windows-Live) may help: I have not tried it out yet though.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is only for email alias, not for domain alias.